# std::sort going overboard

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting

I'm trying to sort a vector of objects using a predicate function and I'm getting some segfaults...

I have a class `Item` and a list of Items in a `vector< Item > _items`. I needed to sort it according to a display order (numerical member of the class) and I just called a simple sort with a predicate function.

```
sort(_items.begin(), _items.end(), sort_item_by_display_order);
```

where the predicate function is

```
bool sort_item_by_display_order (Item i, Item j)
{
    return i.GetDisplayOrder()>j.GetDisplayOrder();
}
```

and GetDisplayOrder is

```
int Item::GetDisplayOrder()
{
    return display_order;
}
```

but... I got some segfaults while doing this. I then added a counter to the predicate function to check how many times it was called and I discovered that when this crashed the counter was bigger then the size of the vector.

After some reading I changed the code to use iterators instead of using the .begin() and .end() (Shouldn't this be the same?!)

So what I have now is

```
vector<Item>::iterator it_start, it_end;
it_start = _items.begin();
it_end = _items.end();
sort(it_start, it_end, sort_item_by_display_order);
```

with the same predicate function.

And now it doesn't crash, but... for most of the sorting I do I get more iterations then the size of the vector I am sorting (which is probably normal)

So... What is the difference between calling sort with `_items.begin()` or `_it_start`. From what I can tell they are the same right?!

One more note. `Item` is a simple base class declared as

```
class Item
{
  private:
  (...)
  public:
  (...)
}
```

As reference I used http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/ and http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=366064.

In the second link they add a const and & to the predicate function arguments which would make my function something like this

```
bool sort_item_by_display_order (const Item& i, const Item& j)
{
    return i.GetDisplayOrder()>j.GetDisplayOrder();
}
```

but I get a compiler error:

```
Item.cpp|1485|error: passing `const Item' as `this' argument of `int Item::GetDisplayOrder()' discards qualifiers|
```

arghhh... The question is... What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I would be wary of using resources from cplusplus.com, they have a reputation of having incomplete and inaccurate information throughout their site (can't say anything specifically to the content of the linked page, however).

Comment: Yes, the calls should be exactly the same.  Also, std::sort should call the predicate at _least_ N * log(N) times, where N is the size of the vector.  Eg, for a vector of 1000 elements, it should call the predicate at _least_ 10000 times.

Comment: When you write that "`Item` is a simple base class", do you mean to say that some elements of your vector will be instances of subclasses of `Item`? If that's the case, then you'll need your vector to hold pointers to the instances, rather than the instances themselves; `vector<const Item *>` rather than `vector<Item>`.

Comment: As for the last error, change `int Item::GetDisplayOrder()` to `int Item::GetDisplayOrder() const` (and declaration too).

Comment: You are not trying to do polymorphism over a `vector`, are you?

Comment: you're passing by value.  you shoudl be passing by const reference, probably.

Comment: @ruakh, I don't think it's technically possible to make `vector<Item>` hold any instances of derived class.

Comment: and back to the issue of difference in behavior, I think the bug is elsewhere and it's just that this particular way of coding it makes it surface.

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker: really?  Codepad seems to allow it: http://codepad.org/JBLnLRRO.  Granted it's probably a bug in the code, but it seems to be slicing fine.

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker, yes, that was my point. :-) &nbsp; You can write code that looks like it's inserting the derived-class instance, but since it's just calling the base-class's copy constructor, the end result is that the element is only an instance of the base class.

Comment: @Mooing:  O(N * log(N)) is an upper bound, not a lower bound.  If a 1000-element array is already in order, for instance, a sort could use as little as 1000 comparisons.

Comment: @Nemo: O(N * log(N)) the upper bound of the _complexity_, not the number of comparisons.  There's also the constant to consider, which will always be at least one.  Therefore there is no maximum number of comparisons.  At least in the case of MSVC, std::sort starts as a quicksort, which does zero swaps when they're in order, but still has 10000+ comparisons _minimum_ with the binary predicate.  You are correct that not all sorts have that minimum.  It could theoretically only compare 999 comparisons.

Comment: @MooingDuck, what you did by putting derived instance into the vector is invoked base class copy constructor taking reference to the derived instance for a parameter. So it is base class that ends up in vector.

Comment: Oops, @ruakh already said it :) Well, yes, but this offense in itself is not capital enough to justify segfault.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, it's completely normal for the comparison function to be called more times than you have elements in the collection. That's part of what's meant when we say a sorting algorithm's *complexity* is O(*n* log *n*), for example. The number of comparisons performed on a collection of size *n* will be about *n* × log(*n*). (In fact, *n* is pretty much the *minimum* number of times to call it; otherwise, we wouldn't even be able to tell whether the collection was already sorted in the first place.)

Second, you get an error when you make the parameters be const references because you've declared `GetDisplayOrder` as a non-const method. You're not allowed to call non-const member functions on a const object because the compiler assumes the method will attempt to modify the object, even though in this case it doesn't modify anything. Add `const` to the end of the declaration and definition:

```
int GetDisplayOrder() const;

int Item::GetDisplayOrder() const {
  return display_order;
}
```

Finally, there's the matter of the segmentation faults. The code you've shown here isn't enough to pinpoint a cause. You're correct that changing the way you pass the iterators to `sort` shouldn't have any effect. My suspicion is that your `Item` class needs a copy constructor and an assignment operator, but that they either aren't implemented, or they're not implemented properly. Sorting a vector obviously involves moving items around in the collection, and that requires a working assignment operator. Passing those items to your original comparison function, which accepted parameters by value instead of by const reference, requires a working copy constructor. If you're doing any dynamic memory allocation (such as with `new` or `malloc`) you need to make sure you either make a "deep copy" of the memory when you assign or copy an object, or you figure out a way for multiple objects to *share* the same allocation. If multiple objects think they all own the same block of memory, one of them is likely to free that memory before the others are finished with it, and that can certainly lead to segmentation faults (as you access freed memory).

Comment: Item is "huge" function... if I forgot to add one of the members to the = operator could that cause the error? And I don't have a copy operator implemented as well.

Comment: If you forgot to assign some members in `operator=`, then those members will have values left over from the previous value of the `Item`. That might be a problem. It could also be a problem to omit the copy constructor. If you had to implement the assignment operator, then you probably also need a copy constructor and a destructor. (See "Rule of three.")

Comment: Most of the members of my class are simple types int, bool and... std::string. std::string is a complex type which will handle it's own allocation dealocation which I can't control. But what really worries me is why did my code stop crashing when I replaced the iterators...

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Rob Kennedy said, try putting a breakpoint in `std::swap` (the `std::sort` actually swaps elements to move them around). You could even implement your own `swap` and do a little bit of "printf debugging" if you can't use the debugger for whatever reason.

When you hit the breakpoint, observe carefully whether objects are copied around correctly and ensure nothing gets corrupted. The idea is to try to locate the exact place of the corruption, that may not necessarily crash the program right away, but leads to ill effects later.